# Import German decimal numbers from website

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using `IMPORTHTML` to read a table from a webpage into a google sheet. I am, in fact, only interested in a single entry of said table (if there are better ways to do it feel free to share^^), a number.

The problem is that the website is in German, where `,` is used as a decimal separator instead of `.`. I can replace this no problem, unless the number is less than one. Say the number is `0,54`. Google sheets will load it in, recognize it as a number and discard the zero and the comma, giving me only `54`. However, `54` is also a possible value, so I have no way to know which value is the correct one.

Is there a way to tell google to load the table content as string, or not change it?

Switching my google docs to German is not an option, as then I have to use `;`, `\` and other seperators in all commands...

Here is the command I use to get the value, it works unless the number has a leading zero:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(query(query(IMPORTHTML("https://www.boerse.de/dividenden/ATundT-Aktie/US00206R1023","table",3),"Select * OFFSET 1",0),"Select Col2 where Col1='2021'"),",","."))
```

Answer (score 0):

full table:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE({
 QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TO_TEXT(IMPORTDATA(A1)), 6000, 1), 
 "where Col1 matches '<td>\d.*</td>'"), QUERY(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TO_TEXT(IMPORTDATA(A1)), 6000, 2), 
 "where Col1 matches '<td class=.alignright.*'")),,9^9)), 
 "where Col1 contains '</td>'")}, "<\/\w+>|<\w+.*?>|.$", ), " ", "."))
```

[image]

---

and then query it like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE({
 QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TO_TEXT(IMPORTDATA(A1)), 6000, 1), 
 "where Col1 matches '<td>\d.*</td>'"), QUERY(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TO_TEXT(IMPORTDATA(A1)), 6000, 2), 
 "where Col1 matches '<td class=.alignright.*'")),,9^9)), 
 "where Col1 contains '</td>'")}, "<\/\w+>|<\w+.*?>|.$", ), " ", "."), 
 "select Col2 where Col1 = '2021'")*1)
```

[image]

Comment: Same outcome, unfortunately. But I learned that you can du multiple lines in commands, so thanks for that already. :) edit: or can you? I can copy your stuff in and it stays in multiple lines, but I can't make a linebreak in the command field...

Comment: can you share a url?

Comment: I currently use this one for testing, the others are similar: https://www.boerse.de/dividenden/ATundT-Aktie/US00206R1023  The value for 2021 is less than one and breaks my stuff...

Comment: Oh wow, that one looks complicated... But it works, thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think a much simpler way to do this would be to have a "European Download sheet"

Create a new spreadsheet, then File>Spreadsheet Settings and change the locale to Germany.  Then put the regular old IMPORTHTML code in cell A1:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.boerse.de/dividenden/ATundT-Aktie/US00206R1023";"table";3)
```

Then back on your "non-european" sheet, you can run a regular vlookup into that other sheet with an importrange like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(2021,IMPORTRANGE(["sheet key"],["tab name!A:B"]),2,0))
```

Before that works, you'll need to "authorize" the connection between the sheets.  Easiest way is to put a call to a random cell on the source sheet so that you'll be prompted to "allow access".

something like:

```
=IMPORTRANGE(["sheet key"],["tab name!A1"])
```

Maybe there are other european imports that you can keep on that sheet for any other european scraping you need to do.